# Java watcher - How to know if a file is fully created

Tags: java

Hi i implemented a java file watcher which reads the file when it is created.

It works fine on development machine. I created a few files and through the logs, the ENTRY_CREATE is called and my program reads the files as expected. The ENTRY_MODIFY is not called.

But on a production machine it behaves differently. Many files are written to the directory, and my program failed to read the files properly when the ENTRY_CREATE is called. I noticed there were a few ENTRY_MODIFY.

How do I tell if the file is completed so my program can read the file properly. From [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933557/how-to-tell-when-a-file-is-done-copying-into-a-watched-directory), it mentioned that the file is done when the last modified is called. But how do i know? And sometimes ENTRY_MODIFY is not called.

Comment: Do you use the same operating system on your development machine and on the production machine?

Comment: a Mac for development, a debian for production

Answer (score 1):

I decided to check the file lastmodified. If it stop changing, I continue to process the file. I am monitoring the the logs and if all goes well, I will use this method.

```
// Check if file is done created by checking change in date modified
    File file = new File("...../filepath");
    long tmpFileLastModified = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        long fileLastModified = file.lastModified();

        if (fileLastModified != tmpFileLastModified) {
            tmpFileLastModified = fileLastModified;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            msLogger.debug("fileModifiedCallback: File done modified");
            break;
        }

        counter++;
    }

// do something with the file
```