# How to check whether the folder processing is completed or not in java

Tags: java

I have a situation, where I have created new Folder 'XYZ' and I am copying huge files to 'XYZ' folder. I need a condition check whether the copying files to 'XYZ' folder is completed or not, before I begin my process on 'XYZ' folder.

Thanks

Comment: That depends on how you're copying. Please post the code.

Comment: `if (!stillCopying()) { beginYourProcess() }` ... this is the answer of the same level of detail and clarity as your question. Please take the time to ask a proper question if you want people to help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell when a File is "Done" copying into a watched Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933557/how-to-tell-when-a-file-is-done-copying-into-a-watched-directory)

Comment: Copying the files manually to 'XYZ' folder.

Comment: @HanumanthReddy what do you mean by manually ? Like drag and drop ?

Comment: @ vincrichaud, Yes like drag and drop.

Comment: Please edit your question -  your are copying file manually and you want to know the status in java code whether it is copied or not, please do draft question properly to help you out

Comment: @Afgan, my question is correct only.
The other team will be doing the copy mechanism, and I am making the process automation from there.

Comment: First, we get its current file size. and we will wait for 200ms(can be less or more) and check for the size again. If the size differs, we will retry for 5 times. Only when the file size stops growing, the File will be marked as COMPLETED.(i.e. return true). hope you know the file name